Tomcat getting stopped while running through jenkins
I'm getting an issue while starting and stopping tomcat through jenkins.
I'm using Jenkins war and Apache tomcat tar file and in my pipeline script simply I'm trying to restart and start the tomcat. I'm getting logs as tomcat started but in catalina.log it's getting stopped just after some seconds.
    pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        
        stage('stop catalina'){
            steps{
                sh """
                sh /home/ayush/Apache/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/bin/catalina.sh stop
                """
            }
        }
   


        
        stage('start catalina'){
            steps{
                sh """
               cd /home/ayush/Apache/apache-tomcat-10.1.28/bin/
               nohup sh catalina.sh start 1>nohup.out 2>nohup.err &
                sleep 10
                """
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}

Below is the catallina.log

25-Sep-2024 00:36:13.538 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
25-Sep-2024 00:36:13.549 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [464] milliseconds
25-Sep-2024 00:36:22.815 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
25-Sep-2024 00:36:22.837 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
25-Sep-2024 00:36:22.945 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
25-Sep-2024 00:36:22.997 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]

Please help me with this why it's getting stopped suddenly.
